# CSS text alignment on mac

Tags: html, css, macos, firefox, opera

So I have CSS problems on mac. This problem is present on FF and Opera on mac.
On windows there are no problems on any browser I have tested(IE, FF, Opera, Chrome).

The problem is with misaligning `>` simbols on the gray area showed bellow.

This is how it looks when it is ok on windows platform:
[image]

This is the problematic misalignment of `>` on mac in FF(This does not happen on chrome and safari)
[image]

I have no idea how to fix this since the `>` symbols are not enclosed in any html element...

I did not code this myself so I would like to fix this with css or javascript.

Thanks for the help!

For more clarity: This is the PHP code that generates the navigation path(links seperated by > in gray area)

```
     <a href="/">Kartes.lv</a> <?php echo '&gt; '; ?>
<?
                        $strTitle = '';
                        $strBuf = '';
                        for ($i=1; $i<count($_page_path); $i++)
                        {
                            if ($_page_path[$i+1][0])
                            {
                                $strLink = '<a '. (!isset($_page_path[$i+2]) ? ' class="last" ' : '') .'href="/?wp='. $_page_path[$i+1][0] .'&lg='.(isset($_GET['lg']) ? $_GET['lg'] : '2').'&p=0">'.$_page_path[$i][1].'</a>';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $strLink = $_page_path[$i][1];
                            }

                            if (trim($_page_path[$i][1]) != '')
                                $strTitle = $_page_path[$i][1];                            

                            if ($strBuf != '')
                            {
                                echo $strBuf . ($strLink != '' ? ' &gt; ' : '');
                            }
                            $strBuf = $strLink;
                        }
                        echo $strBuf;                        
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with conflicting css styles, `vertical-align: top` on container div but `vertical-align: center` on child a elements which resulted in misalignment.

Thanks to everyone who spent time here anyway!